# Count Items Worth Over and Under $100 per Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find orders placed by customers that total at least $250. Then I need to compare the actual items they purchased per order, and see how many are worth below or under $100.

So say they purchased 5 items total. Two are worth at least $100. Three are less. The results would be:

```
OrderID  LargeItems  SmallItems  Total
1112     2           3           5
```

So that's a rough example of what I'm after.

Right now I have:

```
--Total Items purchased in orders worth $250 or more
SELECT O.OrderID,COUNT(OP.Price) as 'Total'
FROM dbo.tblOrder O WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblOrderProduct OP WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON O.OrderID=OP.OrderID
WHERE O.OrderDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-01-01'
    and O.Total >= 250
group by O.OrderID
order by O.OrderID
```

If you can't easily tell:

- OP.Pprice is the price of individual items in the order
- O.Total is the order total

I'm missing the Large and Small item columns. How can I put those separate counts in as well?

Thanks! Please ask if you need any extra info.

Comment: Does OrderDate have any time associated with it? If so [you need to stop using BETWEEN right now](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx). I suspect your query isn't suppose to include orders from 2013-01-01 at midnight...

Comment: Ah, yeah. So I should just use >= or something like that instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statements to do this:

```
SELECT O.OrderID
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN OP.Price >= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'LargeItems'
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN OP.Price < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'SmallItems'
       ,COUNT(OP.Price) as 'Total'
FROM dbo.tblOrder O WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblOrderProduct OP WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON O.OrderID=OP.OrderID
WHERE O.OrderDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-01-01'
    and O.Total >= 250
group by O.OrderID
order by O.OrderID
```